# Setting Image source of react native with image and uri dynamically

Tags: react-native

I want to display a loader image till my image is loaded to the react-native Image. Back is an image which is stored locally and it has been imported to the screen.

This code gives me a blank screen for 'Back' image. When I set the source as source={Back} it works. But the following doesn't work. What am I doing wrong here?

```
<View style={styles.imageWrapper}>
                    <NonClickableImage 
                        source={this.state.loaded ? Back : {uri: detailedMovement.image}}
                        resizeMode="stretch"
                        width={width - 20}
                        height={200} 
                        onLoad={() => this._onMovementImageLoaded()}
                    />
                </View>
```

Comment: How is 'Back' defined? You may need to wrap it in an object, like `source={this.state.loaded ? { Back } : {uri: detailedMovement.image}}`

Comment: have you tried https://github.com/oblador/react-native-image-progress

Answer (score 0):

I think your logic needs to be:

```
{!this.state.loaded ? Back : {uri: detailedMovement.image}}
```

Because you want to show the `Back` icon when the `state` is NOT `loaded`. Currently, if the state is loaded, then you display `Back`.

Comment: Yes. thanks ACVM. And still this doesnt work. Back image is displayed for a mili second and then there is a blank screen till the image get loaded. How can I achieve this? I want to display a loader till the Image gets loaded

Comment: How/when are you updating `this.state.loaded`? Is it in the `this._onMovementImageLoaded()` function? If so, then you're tracking when the `Back` image is loaded and not your `uri` image. Also, rather than creating a lambda in the line `() => this._onMovementImageLoaded()` you can simply do `this._onMovementImageLoaded` without the invocation parenthesis to pass in the function as a variable.

Comment: If you wanted to do this, I'd recommend using 2 `Image` components, with the `Back` image sitting on top of the `uri` image. Once the `uri` image loads in, either hide or remove the `Back` image.